# JS NaN after array[index]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started programming with js again and having some trouble.
This is the code i have problems with:

```
var actual = [10,50,20];
var sum = 0;
for(var i = actual.length; i > 0; i--){
    sum = sum + actual[i];
}
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: JavaScript arrays are indexed starting from 0 up to `length - 1`, so `actual[i]` is `undefined` when `i` is `actual.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start loop from `actual.length-1`, because every array starts from 0, so last element is `actual.length-1` not `actual.length`.

Comment: Yes this worked. Totally forgot that. Thank you. I know theres another bug with the logic but ill figure this one out myself

Answer (score 0):

I see Your calculator code is too complicated.

You do low level operation to add just "1" You multiply all things to 10 and add 1.

Be simple (;

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

var accept = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'-','+','calc'];
var input = [];
function op(value){
  if(accept.indexOf(value) < 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  if(value == 'calc') {
    return calc(); 
  }
  
  input.push(value);
  inputElement.innerHTML = input.join('');
}

function calc() {
  resultElement.innerHTML = eval(input.join(''));
  input = [];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="op(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="op(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="op(3)">3</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="op(4)">4</button>
<button onclick="op(5)">5</button>
<button onclick="op(6)">6</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="op(7)">7</button>
<button onclick="op(8)">8</button>
<button onclick="op(9)">9</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="op(0)">0</button>
<button onclick="op('.')">.</button>
<button onclick="op('calc')">=</button>
<hr/>
<button onclick="op('+')">+</button>
<button onclick="op('-')">-</button>
<hr/>
INPUT:<div id="input"></div>
DISPLAY:<div id="result"></div>
```